# How to unite 2 scripts in one using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making an tkinter app. I have 2 scripts and I have to make an GUI where you can press one button and scripts will be run in sequence. Also I should note that my scripts also use tkinter.

I tried to make it just by making 2 functions for each script and putting them in one button, but it doesn't work right. It's only open window of first script and second one starts only if I close both open windows.

This is what i tried

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
 
def run_script_1():
    # Code for running script 1
    print("Running script 1")
 
def run_script_2():
    # Code for running script 2
    print("Running script 2")
 
def run_both_scripts():
    run_script_1()
    run_script_2()
 
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Script Runner")
root.geometry('600x100')
 
 
frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
 
button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Run Both Scripts", command=run_both_scripts)
button.pack()
 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: maybe you might've forgotten to include your code in the post?

Comment: my code structure: https://pastebin.com/7SHMsRVK

Comment: oh, sorry, I have already attached this code

Comment: Posted code seems to work ok...

Comment: I think so too :(

Comment: So this is solved then?

Comment: Maybe this is the problem: You can only run `Tk()` once in your program. The function starts Tcl and returns a window. To open a new window later you have to use the `Toplevel` class.

Comment: You need to post a [mre]. You should provide code which open a window in your run_script_1(). And by 'unite 2 script', you mean one script importing the other? Or you mean one script executing the other as a child process?